# Is it possible to fail fast Spring tests if the application cannot start?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have this base test class in one Spring Boot module:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WebServiceApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BaseWebServiceTest {
//...
}
```

If for some reason the application cannot start (in my case, if localstack docker image is not started of if Spring Cloud Contract stubs are not available, etc) the tests are still being run and obviously they all fail. Is there any way of skipping all tests if ApplicationContext is not loaded?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way of skipping all tests if ApplicationContext is not loaded?

No. There is no way to skip tests automatically if the `ApplicationContext` does not load.

However, you could make use of JUnit 4's *assumption* support and abort the execution of the tests based on some boolean condition that you choose. For example, if you can check whether the docker image started, you could then do something similar to the following.

```java
public static boolean dockerImagedStarted() {
    // return true if the Docker image started...
}

@BeforeClass
public static void ensureDockerImageStarted() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(dockerImagedStarted());
}
```

p.s. please note that there is an open JIRA issue requesting a built-in feature to avoid repeated attempts to load an `ApplicationContext`. See [SPR-9548](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9548) for details.

Comment: So the only way is taking into consideration all possible causes for the Spring app to not start and treat these in static methods :(

Comment: If you would like Spring to support such a feature, feel free to vote and/or comment here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9548

Answer (score 1):

You can create a runner that will ignore your tests in case that the `ApplicationContext` is not loaded

```
public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public CustomRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isIgnored(FrameworkMethod child) {
        return shouldIgnore() || super.isIgnored(child);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return if your test should be ignored or not
     */
    private boolean shouldIgnore() {
        // Some check if your docker is up

        return true;
    }
}
```

And the use [`@RunWith`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) with the `CustomRunner` you have created

```
@RunWith(CustomRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WebServiceApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BaseWebServiceTest {
//...
}
```

Comment: My problem here is what check to put in the `shouldIgnore()`. Could be plenty reason why the ApplicationContext is not loaded. Optimally, I would like to be able to check if ApplicationContext is loaded, somehow. Is there any option for this?

Comment: mmm, sorry but i can think on something